# Get ListView value

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

I am trying to get data from a listview box and have been unsuccessful.

```
<ListView Name="lst_CallData" Width="950" Height="500" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col0}" Width="150" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="Num" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" Width="200" />
      <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" Width="200" />
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

I am trying to get the data out of Col2 but all avenues I have tried have only given me a string of all the data in the list. I tried to use:

```
DataRow selectedRow = lst_CallData.SelectedItem as DataRow;
```

but datarow does not exists in the current context.

Comment: Use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I use dataBinding for the rest of my program, but I am unsure of how to use it here for just this listview.

Comment: `<ListView ItemSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem}"/>` - that's it.

Comment: Would you care to write up a short answer, @HighCore, please ^-^. This tag needs more answered questions...

Comment: If you are using DataTable object as ItemsSource then it should return DataRowView. You can get DataRow from DataRowView's Row property.

Answer (score 1):

When writing WPF, you have to take the time to organise your data type classes properly. By this, I mean don't use a horrible old `DataTable` with its antiquated `DataRow` elements... instead, define your own class, One that suits the purpose exactly. Importantly, if you have your own class, then you can start to take advantage of interfaces like [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to help with automatic UI updates and data validation.

If you created a class for your data, then you could have an `ObservableCollection` full of them in a property, lets say named `SomeCollection`. If you added another property of the type of your class named `SomeItem`, you could then data bind these properties to the `ListView` as @HighCore correctly showed you:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SomeItem}" />
```

Then to access the selected item at any time from the code behind or view model, you can just access the `SomeItem` property. As this property is of the type of your custom class, then you can now simply access any of its properties by name. For example, if you had the relevant properties and the need, you could do something like this:

```
public void SaveTextFile()
{
    File.WriteAllText(SomeItem.FilePath, SomeItem.Text);
}
```

So anyway, *that* is what HighCore was eluding to and the way that MVVM developers would suggest, but there is a much quicker way too. If you have data bound items in the `ListView`, then you can just access the `ListView.SelectedItem` property directly from the code behind if you have named your `ListView`:

```
YourDataType selectedItem = (YourDataType)lst_CallData.SelectedItem;
```

... where `YourDataType` is the type of objects in the collection that is data bound to the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

The following is the way I tried and able to get data row or entire table object:

[XAML]

```
   <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <localData:MyData />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <ListView Name="lst_CallData" Width="500" ItemsSource="{Binding MyTable}" SelectionChanged="lst_CallData_SelectionChanged" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col0}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Num" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" Width="200" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" Width="200" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

[C#]

```
private void lst_CallData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView selectedRowView = this.lst_CallData.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        if(selectedRowView != null)
        {
            DataRow selectedRow = selectedRowView.Row; // To get the partcular data row
            DataTable inputTable = selectedRowView.DataView.Table; //To get the entire table data
        }
    }
```