# How to get the column value when a row is selected in wpf listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I've a listview with two columns define like below:

```
 <ListView x:Name="HistoryTabLv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="164" Width="275" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFFBFCFC" BorderBrush="#FFCFCFCF" BorderThickness="1" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="HistoryTabLv_SelectionChanged">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column1" Header="Column1" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNum}" />
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="Column2" Header="Column2" Width="95" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Country}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

I insert the data like:

```
HistoryTabLv.Items.Insert(0, new { PhoneNum = data1, Country = data2});
```

All of the above works well. My question is how can I get the column value when I selected certain row? Let say I selected first row and I want the "Hi1" to be displayed in a textbox. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561071/get-listview-value

Comment: Imho this would be easier if you had a normal class as the item instead of an anonymous type. Is that possible?